# Can I somehow select a specific element from dropdown list on the page via splinter module in Python

Tags: python, html, testing, splinter

Can I somehow select a specific element from dropdown list on the page via splinter module in Python?

I have the following HTML code:

```
<select id="xyz">
   <optgroup label="Group1">
      <option value="1">pick1</option>
      <option value="2">pick2</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Group2">
       <option value="3">pick3</option>
       <option value="4">pick4</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

Suppose that I need to select "pick3" option. How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First find the `select` element using [`find_by_id()`](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/api/driver-and-element-api.html#splinter.driver.DriverAPI.find_by_id) and use [`select()`](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/api/driver-and-element-api.html#splinter.driver.DriverAPI.select) method to select an option:

```
element = browser.find_by_id('xyz').first
element.select('3')
```

Alternative solution would be to use [`find_by_xpath()`](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/api/driver-and-element-api.html#splinter.driver.DriverAPI.find_by_xpath) and [`click()`](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/docs/api/driver-and-element-api.html#splinter.driver.ElementAPI.click):

```
element = browser.find_by_xpath('//select[@id="xyz"]//option[@value="3"]').first
element.click()
```

Comment: It gives me the following error: "AttributeError: 'ElementList' object has no attribute '_element'"

Comment: @FrozenHeart oops, edited the answer (`find_by_id()` returns a list, need to get the first item from it).

Comment: @FrozenHeart ok, please check the `UPD` section.

Comment: @FrozenHeart I suspect this is because the `select` doesn't have a `name`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
browser.find_option_by_text('pick3').first.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following using `select_by_text()` method-

```
browser.find_by_id('xyz').select_by_text("pick3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i'm bumping up against this right now I thought i'd chime in on this. Finding the select element and doing 'select(option_value)' does this xpath: '//select[@name="%s"]/option[@value="%s"]' to find the option. This xpath fails if you're using optgroups like in your example.

element = browser.find_by_xpath('//select[@id="xyz"]//option[@value="3"]').first
element.click()
as alecxe suggests should do the trick.

Comment: This answer seems to be an acknowledgement that another answer worked. We're glad that it did -- But instead of a new post or a comment, an upvote would be most appropriate.